# Remove height and width from inline styles

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to remove inline heights and widths from my elements.  Solving it for images was simple:

```
def remove_dimension_tags(tag):
    for attribute in ["width", "height"]:
        del tag[attribute]
    return tag
```

But I'm not sure how to go about processing something like this:

```
<div id="attachment_9565" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 2010px;background-color:red">
```

when I would want to leave the background-color (for example) or any other style attributes other than height or width.

The only way I can think of doing it is with a regex but last time I suggested something like that the spirit of StackOverflow came out of my computer and murdered my first-born.

Comment: And if I _am_ supposed to use a regex... a little help with that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any problem with using regex _on the contents of the style attribute_, but find that attribute using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full walk-through would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

string = """
    <div id="attachment_9565" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 2010px;background-color:red">
        <p>Some line here</p>
        <hr/>
        <p>Some other beautiful text over here</p>
    </div>
    """

# look for width or height, followed by not a ;
rx = re.compile(r'(?:width|height):[^;]+;?')

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, "html5lib")

for div in soup.findAll('div'):
    div['style'] = rx.sub("", string)
```

As stated by others, using regular expressions **on the actual value** is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex if you want, but there is a simpler way.

Use [`cssutils`](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/README.html#documentation) for a simpler css parsing

A simple example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cssutils

s = '<div id="attachment_9565" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 2010px;background-color:red">'

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div")
div_style = cssutils.parseStyle(div["style"])
del div_style["width"]
div["style"] = div_style.cssText
print (div)
```

Outputs:

```
>>><div class="wp-caption aligncenter" id="attachment_9565" style="background-color: red"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import bs4

html = '''<div id="attachment_9565" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 2010px;background-color:red">'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Tag's attribute is a dict object, you can modify it like a dict:

get item:

```
soup.div.attrs

{'class': ['wp-caption', 'aligncenter'],
 'id': 'attachment_9565',
 'style': 'width: 2010px;background-color:red'}
```

set item:

```
soup.div.attrs['style'] = soup.div.attrs['style'].split(';')[-1]

{'class': ['wp-caption', 'aligncenter'],
 'id': 'attachment_9565',
 'style': 'background-color:red'}
```

Use Regex:

```
soup.div.attrs['style'] = re.search(r'background-color:\w+', soup.div.attrs['style']).group()
```

Comment: This only works if I know the order of the attributes, and how many.

Comment: Again, though, if height and width are interspersed with any number of elements in any order, this wouldn't work.

Comment: I've already accepted an answer, but your regex explicitly tests for background-color, which is just one of many possible options.