# Regex for deleting two patterns in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to parse HTML.  So, confessing that sin right off the bat.  If you have a better way, answer it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495214/remove-height-and-width-from-inline-styles) because I feel dirty and wrong.

Nonetheless, I can't find the answer to this regex question which can apply to non-HTML.

I have a string like:

```
tag ='style="width: 2010px; background-color: red; height: 200px; font-size: 12px"'
```

and want to remove the width and height elements only, so I tried:

```
    r = r'style="(width:\s?\d+px;?)|(height:\s?\d+px;?)'
    tag = re.sub(r, "", tag)
```

The pattern seems to match in [regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/QtkhTN/1) but I'm getting a `TypeError: 'expected string or buffer`.

Comment: Works for me without modifications: `' background-color: red;  font-size: 12px"'`.

Comment: Are you _sure_ tag is a string, and not a BeautifulSoup element or some other object?

Comment: Ah.  Yup.  It's a Beautiful Soup Element.

Comment: Then there's your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?:width|height):\s?\d+px;?\s?
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/D4Qovz/2)**

**python**

```
import re
regex = r"(?:width|height):\s?\d+px;?\s?"
test_str = '<div id="attachment_9565" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 2010px;background-color:red;height:200px">'
subst = ""
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```